# Could not load file or assembly, I think this is a problem with the Azure Function version, but I don't know how to solve it

Tags: azure-functions

This is a company project, when I run this project It will report the following errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4euse.png)
I know this version maybe wrong, I try to find solution, I delete the \AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools Floder, but when I restart the project, vs2017 will download old version and work , How should I replace the old version

I try to delete the \AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools ,and get the correct version from colleagues,
but it doesn't work, each time it will re download version 2.0.1-beta.25[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWBlB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot you have attached, you are getting the below error

"could not load file or assembly Microsoft.azure.webjobs.host v 3.0.14.0"

You can remove the nuget package and install the required version of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs nuget package. Latest version is 3.0.33

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs

Once you have installed the nuget package, please rebuild the project and check if the issue is resolved or not.